# start method from another class

Tags: android

Alright, i have read many different views on how to do this with no success. Maybe i am missing something or not doing something right, so any help i appreciate...

So, i have 2 Classes. Lets say Class A is an activity and has a public method called classAmethod();

Now, Class B actually extends a BroadcastReceiver. So in Class B i need to start classAmethod();

--

So far when i try this, it will want to make it static. But i cant do that. I have tried some other methods that dont make it static but for some reason it automatically wants it to be static and if something isn't it will FC once the method is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can do this so I'll just outline 2 ways I would do this.

Option 1. use a listener

create an interface

```
public interface Listener {

public abstract void onEvent();

}
```

in the broadcast receiver create a static reference and setter

```
private static MessageListener mListener = null;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //stuff
        if(mListener != null)
             mListener.onEvent();   
}

public static void setListener(Listener l) {
    mListener = l;
}
```

then implement the listener in the Activity

```
class MyActivity implements Listener{

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        //register the listener, should probably unregister in onDestroy
        BroadCastReceiver.setListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Option 2. use an intent

In the broadcast receiver

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
Bundle bundleToSend = new Bundle(); 
//BUNDLE_EXTRA,DO_SOME_ACTION and ACTION_KEY are just constants so just define them somewhere
bundleToSend.putInt(ACTION_KEY, DO_SOME_ACTION);        
intent.putExtra(BUNDLE_EXTRA, bundleToSend);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

The flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` will start the activity if its not started or if it is running it will be caught in `onNewIntent()` so you will need to put some code in both the `onCreate()` and `onNewIntent()` to extract the bundle and check for the action.

```
final Bundle bundleReceived = intent.getBundleExtra(BUNDLE_EXTRA);
if (bundleReceived.getInt(ACTION_KEY) == DO_SOME_ACTION) {
    //do something
}
```

Option 1 is really only useful for when the broadcast receiver is only going to be receiving when the activity is at the forefront. Option 2 is more versatile and can be used even when the app is not running (eg the broadcast receiver is run in a service started on boot) so that the activity will be started and the action performed no matter the state of the activity.

Comment: Option 1 worked perfectly. The broadcast receiver runs when a notification is received. Such as an SMS. But, i got it going and works fine

Answer (score 0):

methods belong to objects. If you want to call a method it must be done on an object. Therefor if you want to call `classAMethod()` from class B then class B must have a reference to class A.

You haven't described too well what you want to do, its likely that there is a better (more android-y) way of doing what you want to do. Perhaps if you describe what you are trying to do  we can give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a chance to send Activity A self as as context, you can cast that to a type something implements interface which has classAmethod(); and call. make Activity implements interface which has the method classAmethod().

Answer (score 0):

An Android `Activity` is a special class and should not be treated as a 'standard' Java class. In other words (for the purpose of your question), it should be considered as a self-contained class and as such shouldn't expose public methods to other (external) classes.

If you want your `BroadcastReceiver` to have access to methods in your `Activity` then define the `BroadcastReceiver` as an inner class of your `Activity`...

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    ...

    private class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        // Once instantiated and registered by MyActivity, can
        // access methods and fields of MyActivity

    }
}
```